# Pix, can't debug shaders

Tags: shader, directx-9

I can't get Pix to debug shaders. I've used it before totally fine, but today I keep receiving this error when trying to debug either a vertex or pixel shader:

A call that previously succeeded failed furing playback:

EID: 8 Call: IDirect3D9::CreateDevice() HRESULT:D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE

For more information click 'Help'.

Help brings up this:

```
"Playback failure is the error state that occurs following a successful timing capture.

There are many reasons why a call that succeeded at capture time can fail during PIX playback. Here are some common causes:

If the run file was captured on a system with different capabilities or more video memory. Also, PIX Win will use up more video memory than the original title did when it allowed debugging.

It can also occur if your Direct3D control panel settings are different from when the run file was captured. Some Direct3D 9 calls only fail when the debug runtime is active.

In the case of Direct3D 9 playback, the mesh viewer and shader debugging potentially use different device settings than the original application that can cause playback failures. For example, the shader debugging has to use a reference device. In this situation, there is a possibility that the HW device supports settings that are not supported under the reference device like StretchRect() filters. "
```

I don't really understand why it would work one day but not the next, I'm going to investigate my graphic card's drivers but I've no real understanding regarding how to check the errors above.

I should also add I'm using Pix with a DirecX 9 XNA application. I've tried testing both a debug build and a release build. I've disabled D3D analysis and am using frame captures.

If anybody has any ideas what it could be please help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, does it work if you use software instead of hardware to do the vertex processing?

i.e.

Direct3D.CreateDevice (D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, HWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, D3DInit, Device);

If nothing else has changed since the last time you ran your code, maybe your drivers (or some settings in the DirectX control panel) were modified.

Comment: I have no control over that. It's all done through XNA. My thoughts were the same. I updated my drivers a few days ago but still didn't fix it. Maybe a system restore might work.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests a hardware failure, in order to solve that I think you might really need to restore the system some what.

but in terms of debugging a shader, it's not necessarily XNA bounded, you could create a stub D3D program even use software pipeline suggested by @crazylpfan , then you can attach your PIX to that program for the debugging.